# adding code to imagebutton in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that displays data that I retrieved from a database along with an imageButton Field.
How can I get to the eventhandler of the imageButton so that I can add code to redirect the Image to a different we page when I click on it?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdBooksRated" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" 
        Font-Names = "Arial" > 
        <Columns> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="title" HeaderText ="ID" /> 

            <asp:TemplateField> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl ='<%# Eval("pictureUrl")%>' runat="server" /> 
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
        </Columns>  
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to pass anything to the handler, you could simply define an OnClick event handler.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" 
  OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" ImageUrl ='<%# Eval("pictureUrl")%>' runat="server" />


  void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
  {
     // your code here.
  }
```

if you do have to pass some bound data, you can use [OnCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.oncommand.aspx) method. The msdn post has an example.